# My C++ Visual Studio program ignores the Swedish characters å, ä, and ö during input via Win terminal

Tags: c++, utf-8, character-encoding, visual-studio-2022, windows-11

I've encountered a, hopefully, slight problem during a programming endeavor inside Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 11!

Whenever I input å, ä, and ö into my running program using a getline into a string variable, it simply ignores these characters. For example, if I input the Swedish name Måns, the string variable then holds "m" but not "åns", and if I input Bergström, it holds "Bergstr" but not "Öm". The windows terminal outputs the former letters correctly, and when I read them from a text file they store properly into a string. The problem occurs only when I input these via the windows terminal; then the string variable omits the aforementioned characters.

What I've tried to do:

1. Saved all pertinent file encodings to either Unicode (UTF-8 without signature) - Codepage 65001, Nordic (DOS) - Codepage 865, or Western European - Codepage 1252
2. Used std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "") and std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "sv_SE.UTF-8")
3. Went into the Windows settings -> Time & language -> Language & Region -> Administrative language settings -> Change system language -> checked a box saying "Beta: use Unicode UTF-8 for global language support"

I'm pretty lost, to say the least haha

Could anyone help me, please? :)

(By the way, I am a big programming newbie, so I don't think I'll understand much advanced or verbatim code stuff.)

Minimal reproducible code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>


int main() 
{
 
std::string getTextFromFile, 
stand, input;

stand = "Mjölk";

std::cout << stand << std::endl; //correctly outputs "Mjölk" into the terminal
  
std::fstream file("names.txt"); //file with words having the Swedish letters å, ä, and ö. 

file >> getTextFromfile; //let's say it now includes "Måns".

std::cout << getTextFromFile << std::endl; //correctly outputs "Måns" into the terminal. 

std::getline(std::cin, input); //we input "Måns"

std::cout << input << std::endl; //only outputs "M"; "åns" is missing. 



  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [example].

Comment: *the string variable then holds "m" but not "åns"* -- How did you determine what the string variable holds?  What happens if you attempt to hardcode the string with those characters, instead of using `std::getline`?  Even though you are beginner, you should be aware of the ways to, at the very least, get an understanding of what the problem is.  You do that by performing different experiments to see if it's a problem with `getline`, or `std::string` not "working" or some other issue.

Comment: Done! Provided a little code example! @JohnFilleau

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You're right! I'm just a bit stupid  Fixed it now. Won't happen again!

Comment: Did you try using just `std::cin`?  This could be a keyboard input issue, as you're claiming that reading from a file with the Swedish characters displays the string correctly.  Or what you could do is compare, byte-by-byte to what you get when you read in from a file, and what the `std::cin` or `std::getline` gives you, and see where the string contents differ.

Comment: Windows command line window uses a different character set than the rest of Windows. Use `chcp` to see what it is.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I am more than open for criticism. Like I stated, I am a mere beginner, so of course constructive criticism is more than welcome, like the one you gave me concerning the reproducible code example, which I found very helpful to make my problem clear. I did not deflect anything, or at least in my mind I didn't. 

About the self depricating part, it was not actually meant as a matter of fact statement on my part. You know it was just the "oh stupid of me" type of remark, and was not meant to be taken seriously. Anyhow, I shoud've been more respectful, and it won't happen again.

Comment: @MarkRansom Hi! Typing chcp, I got back "Active code page 65001", which is the UTF-8 character set I think.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hello again! I tried using std::cin and performed byte-by-byte to see what each variable holds. Both std::getline and std::cin only has "M", but the content from my file, still outputs and holds "Måns" correctly.